# Android Notifications

Tags: android

Im trying to start a new activity once i press a notification...the related code is:

```
NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  

Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.android, "New E-mail", System.currentTimeMillis());  

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, DatabaseActivity.class), 0);  

note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "New E-mail", "You have one unread message.", intent);  

notifManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note);
```

But the activity just dsnt begin..the notification pops up..but if i click it nothin happens...plz advice!!!

Comment: What do you see on DDMS?

Comment: ddms runs normal...no errors no nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Pardon the obvious question but is DatabaseActivity referenced in your manifest?

Comment: also ive tried removin the notification by using the flag_auto _cancel...even that dsnt work...are the two related or.....

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use getApplicationContext() instead of this in the pendingIntent definition.